# LIKE... AND NOT... sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I am creating a query in which i am selecting data from multiple tables, however, i do not want to select the entry that my users are currently viewing. I have completed this in other query using the AND NOT syntax but when using this in conjunction with LIKE i still return the row i am NOT looking for?

The syntax has no errors when i run but still is incorrect. Here is my query.

```
SELECT id AS num, mix_title AS title, table_type AS type, header, post_date, counter 
FROM mixes
WHERE keywords LIKE ('%#workout%')
   OR keywords LIKE ('%#drunk_fairy%')
 AND NOT id='1'
```

I would like the above code to return all LIKE rows but NOT where the id is equal to 1.

Apologies if this has already been asked, i wasn't too sure how to ask the question, Thanks.

Comment: `(keywords LIKE ('%#workout%') OR keywords LIKE ('%#drunk_fairy%')) AND NOT id='1'`. AND goes before OR...

Comment: ... whereas the parentheses around the strings are superfluous of course. And `id` is a string or why do you use quotes for the 1?

Comment: Thanks guys, i was using quotes for the 1 because the value of id is dynamic and may include a string of numbers and letters in some cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use parentheses because `AND` takes precedence over `OR`:

```
SELECT id AS num, mix_title AS title, table_type AS type, 
       header, post_date, counter 
FROM mixes 
WHERE (keywords LIKE ('%#workout%') OR keywords LIKE('%#drunk_fairy%'))
      AND NOT id='1'
```